# Solution To Global Warming Crisis

Tags: futurama

In Futurama, Farnsworth set-up an idea for all robots to release their exhaust at one location to push Earth away from the Sun thus rendering Earth cooler.  As a side-effect the Earth has more days.

But as we know from science, that if the Earth is pushed 1 Degree back, Earth will freeze and if it is pulled 1 Degree forward, Earth will burn due to the Sun.

Why didn't the Earth freeze when all of the robots moved Earth from orbit?

Comment: Actually, when the [Earth is at it's closest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit#Events_in_the_orbit) to the sun (January), it's a little over 3% closer than when it's at its furthest (July).

Comment: @Izkata The change in orbit... not the consistency of orbit.

Comment: Could you link a source to the 1 Degree forward/back information?

Comment: @DylanYaga There isn't a scientific one.  It's a common (and incorrect, see my previous comment) argument from creationists about Earth having been created in the perfect orbit to support life.

Comment: @Dylan Yaga I can't really link a source because I got this information from one of my science teachers 10+ years ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as the movement due to robot exhaust kept them in the habitable zone, they would have been ok.

[image]

Using the [effective temperature formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_temperature) on wikipedia, I worked out that increasing the fractional extra distance from 0% to 10% alters the temperature by 11 degrees Celsius. Not something catastrophic.

Comment: 11 degrees is quite catastrophic, the ice age was only 4.5 degrees cooler on average than now. Little changes in average temperature cascade into pretty big climate effects.
http://xkcd.com/1379/

Comment: @john each am I have no recollection of writing this.  When I next get my hands on excel I'll work out something more reasonable.